# Transparently connect to VPN in other LAN @linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vpn

I have a linux box, connected via ethernet to `192.168.*.*` LAN. I also need to connect to `10.*.*.*` VPN.

While I ran linux in VirtualBox, the routing was done by VirtualBox for me, linux yielded `10.*.*.*` address and VPN connection was done transparently.

Now I have to setup VPN connection myself. I am able to connect to VPN with Ubuntu’s network manager widget, but it sets routes so that being connected to VPN, I am not able to surf internet through my local LAN connection anymore. I understand, that instead I’d better setup routes by hands [I believe, I am to setup a bridge], so that I was able to connect to both VPN hosts and non-VPN internet simultaneously.

The problem is that I can not realize what query I should google to find a proper routes setup hints. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The following two commands do the trick:

```
# Allow traffic initiated from VPN to access LAN
iptables -I FORWARD -i tun0 -o eth0 \
     -s 10.1.0.0/24 -d 192.168.0.0/24 \
     -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT

# Allow established traffic to pass back and forth
iptables -I FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Persist `iptables` config: https://askubuntu.com/questions/119393/how-to-save-rules-of-the-iptables

[More info](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/BridgingAndRouting).